# Error while creating file null.lobs.db [90062-101]

Tags: java, h2, activiti

I'm trying to deploy my BPMN2.0 workflow through Activiti Engine in Tomcat-7 using **H2** in-mem DB and getting the error below:

```
DEV 10:27:45.258 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.a.e.i.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer - Processing resource com/my/diagram/MyLeaveProcess.bpmn
DEV 10:27:49.554 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.a.e.i.interceptor.CommandContext - Error while closing command context
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Error while creating file null.lobs.db [90062-101]
### The error may involve org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ResourceEntity.insertResource-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: insert into ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY(ID_, REV_, NAME_, BYTES_, DEPLOYMENT_ID_, GENERATED_)     values (?, 1, ?, ?, ?, ?)
### Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Error while creating file null.lobs.db [90062-101]
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:23) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
```

Same workflow working fine if I use the UnitTest.

Comment: `null.lobs.db`? Where does that `null` come from? And more importantly, what is the code?

Comment: It's very encapsulated Activiti provided engine. Does not give much detail on the stack trace either. I'm trying to find myself where is that null coming from.

Comment: You are using a very old version of H2 (from 2009, according to the error code). Would it be possible to upgrade to a more recent version? Most likely you would get a better error message.

Comment: @ThomasMueller You are right. I was using quite an old H2 version and just upgraded to the latest version and the issue itself is gone. So may be Actviti was not compatible with the older version. If you convert your comment to answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to upgrade to a more recent version of H2. Even if this will not solve the problem, you will at least get a better error message.

The build number of H2 is part of the error code, which is [90062-101] in your case. That means you are using build #101, which is from 2009.

Comment: That's quite a clever way to embed the build number.